# Problems using android Wi-Fi Direct API: mChannel = mManager.initialize()

Tags: android, channel, wifi-direct

This is my first post, hope to do it right. I'm trying to create an application using the new android technology Wi-Fi Direct. To do so I was following the tutorial you can find in:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

It's really useful, but when I copy the code, there is something wrong. Exactly with step number 3:

```
WifiP2pManager mManager;
Channel mChannel;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ...
    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
    mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
    ...
}
```

The error is on line:

```
mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
```

And the error message is:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from WifiPesManager.Channel to Channel
```

The recommendation is to make a cast like this:

```
mChannel =  (Channel) mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
```

But when I change my code for that, I have another error while running the application:

```
10-25 12:08:34.845: E/AndroidRuntime(26634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.nacho.WifiDirect/android.nacho.WifiDirect.WifiDirect}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager$Channel cannot be cast to java.nio.channels.Channel
```

Just add the rest of the code is exactly how it appear in the tutorial, but just in case I'm going to add the Activity and also the Broadcast class:

### **Main Activity**

```
package android.nacho.WifiDirect;

import java.nio.channels.Channel;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;

public class WifiDirect extends Activity {

    
    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_direct);
        
        
        //To register the BroadastReceiver
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel =  (Channel) mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null); //It was necessary to make a cast (Channel)
        mReceiver = new WiFiBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this, this);
        
        
        //To define the filter in the BroadcastReceiver
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        
       
    }

    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_wifi_direct, menu);
        return true;
    }
   
    //
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
    
   // unregister the broadcast receiver
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    
}
```

### **WiFiBroadcastReceiver**

```
package android.nacho.WifiDirect;

import java.nio.channels.Channel;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important Wi-Fi p2p events.
 */

public class WiFiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WifiDirect activity;
    //For toast, add also context
    private Context context;

    public WiFiBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, WifiDirect activity, Context context) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        String action = intent.getAction();
        
        
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
             int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
             if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                            
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
             } else {
                 
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wi-Fi Direct is not enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }      
            
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

### **AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.nacho.WifiDirect"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    

   

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WifiDirect"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wifi_direct" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a Channel class coming from the wrong package.

Do `import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;`

instead of

`import java.nio.channels.Channel;`

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. Really silly mistake, and just for trust on Eclipse's tips